# Youtube video plays on only one single tab in firefox

Tags: 18.04, firefox, youtube

I am using Firefox as a browser, I have Ubuntu 18.04.
The main problem is that I can't play two or more youtube videos in different tabs. In fact, once I play the video in the second tab, the first one pauses automatically.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Try with a new profile or in safe mode.

Comment: Interference from extensions / add-ons, etc?

Comment: Thanks Xen, it was caused by an add on : * youtube enhancer*. Problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Xen2050, the problem was due to the extension called "Youtube enhancer", it did not allow me to play two or more youtube videos simultaneously on different tabs.